# How to split the lines in proper format as described?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am writing a program to randomize certain words and I have achieved that. However, when the output is printed, it is all shown in one line.
i.e

{'China': 0, 'Slovakia': 1, 'Benin': 2, 'North Korea': 3, 'Israel': 4, 'Bangladesh': 5}

I need these words to be split in the way as described below:

China, 0
Slovakia, 1
Benin, 2

etc.

I have tried `str.split()` and break but to no avail.

The code that I tried was:

```
with open("countries") as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f ]  
random.shuffle(names)
d = { name: n for n, name in enumerate(names)}
```

But to no avail.
How can I split these words in specified manner above?

Comment: You can use `split()` method.

Comment: you must include the words or line that your are trying to split in the question

Comment: Where do you print the output?

Comment: I print the output into another txt file.

Comment: Do you mean `for key, value in d.items(): print(key, value)`?

Comment: Write your desired output in your question so anybody knows what you exactly want.

Comment: you just want to print them separately or do you want to store them separately in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that, you get the result, and I am expecting the result to be coming from your variable named **d**.

So in order to print that, use the **d**, and traverse through it and print it like this:

```
# YOUR CODE
with open("countries") as f:
    names = [line.strip() for line in f ]  
random.shuffle(names)
d = { name: n for n, name in enumerate(names)}

# Now d has some value, we can traverse through it
# MY CODE
for key, value in d.items():
    print(f"{key}, {value}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
# taking d = {'China': 0, 'Slovakia': 1, 'Benin': 2, 'North Korea': 3, 'Israel': 4, 'Bangladesh': 5}

China, 0
Slovakia, 1
Benin, 2
North Korea, 3
Israel, 4
Bangladesh, 5
```

I don't know whether you have think of this or not, but if you are getting the `dictionary` result, then it is very easy to traverse it and give out the desired output. Thanks, and happy coding!

**WORKING SOLUTION FOR WRITING THE OUTPUT IN ANOTHER FILE**

Please do this, and you will be good to go. I have tested the output myself, and it outputs the data as expected.

> 1. Also, if you use `w` in `open('output.txt', 'w')`, it replaces the data every time with the new one
> 2. In order to make the file contains all the data uniquely, you replace `w` with `a`, make it `open('output.txt', 'a')`

```
import sys

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('output.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f

# make sure you type cast str() to both key and value, 
# else, you will get a blank txt file
for key, value in d.items():
     print(str(key) + ", " + str(value))

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you your code work well! I was just wondering if I could output this into a separate txt/json file?

Comment: Hey @Coder1341985, I have added my answer for the same. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: I have tried all 3 approaches and they all don't seem to work for me :/

Comment: Could you please tell, me what is the error you're getting?

Comment: I am not receiving any errors. However when I check the file that it is meant to be written in and it is still in the same format ({'China': 0, 'Slovakia': 1, 'Benin': 2, 'North Korea': 3, 'Israel': 4, 'Bangladesh': 5}) but the output is still the same...

Comment: Hey @Coder1341985, I have written the workable solution. I hope this will work for you, Thanks. Please mark it right, if the answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```py
output_file = open("output.txt","w+")

for key, value in d.items():
    output_file.write('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))

output_file.close()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I just need to know where to put this. Also TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: @Coder1341985 Oh :)  I fixed it! try again. and put it in end of your code (the code in the question)

Comment: Thank you but I still get the error: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: @Coder1341985 try it again! I don't know why I putted a list in format method!! :| I fixed it!

Comment: Now it is telling me that the output_file.close() is an invalid syntax :/